# focus(); изменение style при нажатии на textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Здравствуйте, вот есть у меня такой скрипт и надо для него сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на textarea менялся стиль на display: block;

```
<textarea id="divid-1"></textarea>
<div style="display:none;" id="otvbl-1">
   text
</div>
```

При этом надо еще передать цифру из id, потому что таких блоков будет много и у каждого будет свое присвоенное число, в данном скрипте присвоение число это 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

textareas.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("focus", function() {
    var idNum = this.id.split('-')[1];   
    document.querySelector('#otvbl-' + idNum).style.display = 'block'; 
  }, true);
});
```

```html
<textarea id="divid-1"></textarea>
<div style="display:none;" id="otvbl-1">
   text
</div>
<br/>

<textarea id="divid-2"></textarea>
<div style="display:none;" id="otvbl-2">
   text2
</div>
<br/>

<textarea id="divid-3"></textarea>
<div style="display:none;" id="otvbl-3">
   text3
</div>
```

Чтоб  `js` загрузился после того, как всё загрузилось, можно обернуть его в
`DOMContentLoaded`:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

    textareas.forEach(function(item) {
      item.addEventListener("focus", function() {
        var idNum = this.id.split('-')[1];   
        document.querySelector('#otvbl-' + idNum).style.display = 'block';  
      }, true);
    }); 
});
```

---

Вообще, как минимум, чтоб не плодить столько айдишников, надо бы просто сделать обертку, в которой будет и textarea и див. И при нажатии фокусе текстарии, брать див в той же обертке, что и textarea. Тогда значительно проще будет

что-то типа:

```js
// document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

    textareas.forEach(function(item) {
      item.addEventListener("focus", function() {
            // this.closest('.wrap').querySelector('textarea+div').style.display = 'block';
       this.closest('.wrap').children[1].style.display = 'block';     
      }, true);
    });  
//   });
```

```css
.wrap > div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div>
     text
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div>
     text2
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div>
     text3
  </div>
</div>
```

C `Jquery` еще проще :)

Comment: Вот во втором случае, если стиль у меня будет записан отдельно в другом файле и просто через include(); подключен. Он изменит этот стиль?

Comment: @СашаОсипов в каком случае? когда изменяется при фокусе или в самом начале? или что конкретно имеется в виду? Можете в css стиль прописать и вместо `block/none` присваивать стиль элементу. Обычно так все делается

Comment: какую библиотку js надо подключить? Можно ссылку пожалуйста

Comment: @СашаОсипов https://jquery.com/  ...... не надо, а можно. С ней порой удобнее

Comment: Ни чего понять не могу, подключил по этой ссылыке https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js но всё равно не работает.

Comment: @СашаОсипов что не работает? Код выше на чистом js. И он рабочий. Для `jquery` надо по другому писать...

Comment: Ну видимо я туплю. я просто вставил весь код на страницу и подключил jquery. http://socialcube.net16.net/ вот ссылка, исходник весь видно.

Comment: @СашаОсипов jquery не делает магии ,если не писать что-то........ а код не работает из-за ошибки http://i.stack.imgur.com/HtTvn.jpg .......устраните её - заработает....всегда смотрите ошибки в консоли....всегда! .....и читайте мануал потом как использовать jquery

Comment: Это на самом хостинге и это ни как не мешает. Он выдает еще одну ошибку в 5 строке кода, где находиться textareas.forEach

Comment: @СашаОсипов ну если вы так уверены, значит код надо обернуть в `DOMContentLoaded` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded  или `onload` https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror  чтоб код срабатывал после того, как вся страница загрузится, удачи

Comment: Я не знаю в чем проблема, в ошибке мне пишет "Uncaught TypeError: textareas.forEach is not a function

Comment: @СашаОсипов пишите код обернув в `DOMContentLoaded` как я написал выше

Comment: Извините, я не знаю просто js и все это введение, можете отредактировать в вашем ответе и показать как это вставляется ...

Comment: @СашаОсипов смотрите

Comment: Все равно не работает :с

Comment: @СашаОсипов потому что `script.onload = function () {` неправильно....... в консоли ошибка даже `Uncaught ReferenceError: script is not defined` ........сделайте `window.onload = function () {`

Comment: Изменил, но теперь при нажатии ни чего не происходит, но ошибок нету

Comment: Нашел способ один.... <textarea onfocus="this.style.display='block'"></textarea> и вот как тут указать, чтобы изменил в div блоке?

Answer (score 0):

Первую часть вопроса можно решить так:

```
textarea:focus + div{
    display: block;
}
```